# cumulative binomial distribution upper bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This question is about the probability that out of $2n$ births there are more girls than boys, with the probability that a girl is born is $p=0.485$
The number of girls born has obviously a binomial distribution.
It is to show that the probability that more girls than boys are born is lower than
$$\binom{2n}{n}(1-p)^n\frac{1-p}{1-2p}$$
The actual chance is obviously $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{2n-k}$$
But I have no idea how to show that this is less than the one above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using that $\binom{2n}{k}$ is maximized when $k=n$ and the geometric sum:
\begin{align}
& \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{2n-k}\\
% 
& =(1-p)^{2n} \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k} \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^k\\ 
% 
& \le(1-p)^{2n} \binom{2n}{n}  \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^k \\ 
% 
& \le (1-p)^{2n} \binom{2n}{n}  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^k \\ 
% 
& = (1-p)^{2n} \binom{2n}{n}   \frac{1}{ 1 - \frac{p}{1-p}} \\
& = (1-p)^{2n} \binom{2n}{n}   \frac{1-p}{ 1-2p } \\
& \le (1-p)^{n} \binom{2n}{n}   \frac{1-p}{ 1-2p }.
\end{align}